# Unable to pass string into a function?

Tags: javascript

My Javascript code is

```
function ad_cart(nm, mmi, pr) {

            alert(imm);
}
```

The value i'm passing from onclick is this

```
onclick="ad_cart(Drafting Factory Folders ,2,3.50)"
```

But it is showing a error as 
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

In mozilla

In chrome the error is

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

But if i pass integer instead of string like

```
 onclick="ad_cart(1,2,3.50)"
```

then it is working fine

Comment: For string to pass into a function as a parameter put it in quotes - like "Drafting Factory Folders" or 'Drafting Factory Folders'

Comment: there is thousand of thousand examples regarding your issue...

Comment: i have tried it but got this syntax error near '

Comment: could you please edit your question with updated code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ad_cart(nm, mmi, pr) {

            alert(imm);
}
```

Seems to spell mistake also, getting `mmi` and showing `imm`

And the string should be wrap by ''

**edit:**

```
function ad_cart(nm, mmi, pr) {

            alert(mmi);
}

ad_cart('string' ,number,number)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
onclick="ad_cart('Drafting Factory Folders' ,2,3.50);"
```

And your function will be like

```
function ad_cart(nm, mmi, pr) {

        alert(mmi);    // Instead of `imm`
}
```

Comment: Chrome says Unexpected token }